# Convert UBB Forum Database to MyBB

Tags: forum, mybb

is there any tools for convert database of UBB forum to MyBB Forum?

Answer (score 1):

You should convert UBB to vBB or phpBB then convert from vBB / phpBB to MyBB.

Just like XenForo doesn't support some kind of forums, I didn't test but it should work!